# What are the best practices for consuming several API's in Android

Tags: android, api

I was hoping someone could help me with a question I have.

If I want to consume data from several API's in android (they are checked once a day for changes) and then I combine all of the data and do something with it, what would be the best way to do this from a resource and memory point of view ?

An example would be getting bus timetables from several bus companies operating in a city and then showing what busses are leaving in the next hour for example, that is relative to your location.

I do know how to consume Rest API's in Android, I am just wondering if there is a better way than calling say 20 API's once a day and storing the data ?

If I have not explained the question well enough please feel free to ask me anything and I will try and explain it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 20 API requests per day does not seem so much to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make a few question about your solution.

Does your solution require the access to 20 different api's and the mobile app will be distributed in more than one user? If the answer is YES then you need a backend. The backend will execute a batch process to access the data from the 20 sources, consolidate the information and will be available for as many client devices require that information.

If the information will be not updated, you can make one call per day to the backend and keep it cached on the device.

If your app get more complex, could even receive notifications about changes on the data so it could update it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: A back end server is certainly a good way to go but I wouldn't say he needs to do that.  If he doesn't want to deal with that it would certainly be possible to do all of this on the device.  That would result in much higher traffic to the APIs, which may or may not be a concern.

Comment: To choose a proper architecture is always a big decision of course. If you take the logic for processing data to the client, mobile or not, you will be tied to update every client in case of fixing a bug or changing a logic. If the logic remains in a central place, the clients will be affected a lot less.